# Ansible: setting up IP addresses from the list

Tags: ansible

I have a list of IPv6 addresses that should be assigned for hosts based on specific hostname. For example:

- host with the name **"myhost-dev1"** should have fd00:1::1/64

  host with the name **"myhost-dev2"** should have fd00:1::2/64

  ...

  host with the name **"myhost-devN"** should have fd00:1::N/64

  ...

  host with the name **"myhost-qa1"** should have fd00:2::1/64

  host with the name **"myhost-qaM"** should have fd00:2::M/64

  ...

```
IPv4 addresses are already assigned.
Question: what is the best way to assign these addresses using Ansible?
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is way, how I resolve it:

1. Create v6.yaml file:

   ```
   myhost-dev1.example.com: fd00:1::1
   myhost-dev2.example.com: fd00:1::2
   ```
2. Added two following tasks:

   ```
   - name: Load IPv6 addresses list
     include_vars:
       file: 'v6.yml'
       name: ipv6_addr

   - name: Apply IPv6 addresses
     blockinfile:
       path: '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0'
       block: |
         IPV6INIT=yes
         IPV6ADDR={{ ipv6_addr[ansible_fqdn] }}
         IPV6_DEFAULTGW=fd00:1::100
   ```